# Vim OmniCppComplete on vectors of pointers

Tags: c++, vim, omnicppcomplete

I might have done something wrong in the set up but is OmniCppComplete supposed to provide the members/functions of classes when doing this?

```
vectorofpointers[0]->
```

At the moment all I get when trying that are things relating to the vector class itself, which obviously isn't very useful. I think it might have been working before I tagged /usr/include/ but I could be wrong.

Also, is it possible to disable the preview window? I find it just clutters up my workspace. And since I enabled ShowPrototypeInAbbr I don't really need it.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to get proper code completion on the objects that are included in the vector, but someone please correct me if I am mistaken.

To disable the preview window, make sure to not set `preview` for the the `completeopt` option, type `:help completeopt` in Vim for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I must have been delusional when I thought I saw it before.

Answer (score 0):

We finally have sane code completion for C++ in Vim using [GCCSense](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/). With GCCSense it is possible to autocomplete on the contents of a vector.